# Display Whole Matrix in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to print a matrix that I've created with Numpy first and then I transformed in with Pandas.

It works fine except that it doesn't print the entire Matrix, but it gives me **...** (maybe because it doesn't fit into the terminal(?). I do not know.

```
def build_transition_matrix(self):
    """
    Method which build the Transition Matrix with the list of tags computed earlier
    Returns
    -------
    :returns transition matrix with all the probabilities displayed in a matrix
    :rtype DataFrame
    """
    transition_matrix = np.zeros((len(self.tags_list), len(self.tags_list)), dtype='float64')
    print("MATRIX INITIALIZED")
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    for rows, tag1 in enumerate(list(self.tags_list)):
        for cols, tag2 in enumerate(list(self.tags_list)):
            transition_matrix[rows, cols] = self.transition_probability(tag2, tag1)[0]/self.transition_probability(tag2, tag1)[1]
    pretty_transition_matrix = pd.DataFrame(transition_matrix, columns=list(self.tags_list), index=list(self.tags_list))
    display(pretty_transition_matrix)
    return pretty_transition_matrix
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set these 4 options:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```